# Token based authentication between web api and mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am stuck in token saving in mvc

While calling web api 2.0 in mvc 5, I want to store generated api token in mvc client side so that next time when I hit action of api that is authorized action so mvc should pass only token to api but api should look first whether token is expired or not if expired create new one.

The problems are:

1: Where to store token in mvc.

2: How to pass to api.

3: How to check in api whether expired or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Owin Middleware in order to store your token.

```
    public string BearerToken
    {
        get { return ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst("AcessToken").Value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store token in cookies in MVC application and when you send request to web api then you need to pass token in Authorization header.